# How to modify list entry in python 2.x, using loop

Tags: python

I have to create many more files in a directory thus I want this to be done in pro grammatically. I selected python but how to solve the following problem

I have a list

> L=['a','b','c']

Now I want to modify the entry in list L as below

> L=['a.txt','b.txt','c.txt']

How to do it?

Comment: Please don't edit your questions to make the existing answers invalid, and instead of asking people to write code for you, at least show what you've tried so far (although to be fair, the 4 people who wrote code for you will probably just write more for you even if you show no effort at all...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *modify* a list, iterate over it using indices:

```
for i in range(len(L))):
    L[i] += '.txt'
```

However in this case you don't really need to modify the list, so you probably want to use list comrehension, as suggested by @Ashwini Chaudhary. however, using list comprehension creates *new* list, so you may assign it again into L:

```
L = [s + '.txt' for s in L]
```

But, if the original variable L is a global or nonlocal variable, the above statement will create new, local variable, that will disappear at the end of the current function, and may create a mess if you tried to access it before the asssignment:

```
>>> L = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> def addtxt():
...     print(L)
...     L = [s + '.txt' for s in L]
...
>>> addtxt()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in addtxt
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'L' referenced before assignment
```

You will need to add `global` (or `nonlocal` in other case) declaration. It is not a clean way to handle this.

So, combining in-place replacement with list comprehension, you get the suggestion from @Jamylak

```
L[:] = [s + '.txt' for s in L]
```

where `[:]` means that the content of the list will be replaced by the right side of the assignment. This will not add local binding, and will fit anywhere the above-mentioned loop will fit.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> L=['a','b','c']
>>> L[:] = [x + '.txt' for x in L]
>>> L
['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
```

The slice assignment `[:]` is used to mutate `L` itself and retain references. eg. This is what happens if you don't use it

```
>>> L=['a','b','c']
>>> L2 = L # you may have a reference like this in your code somewhere
>>> L = [x + '.txt' for x in L] # this simply reassigns the name L to a new value
>>> L
['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
>>> L2 # but doesn't affect the name L2 which is still binded to the old list
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

A little bit simpler than the previous answer:

```
L = [i + '.txt' for i in L]
```

or

```
for i, string in enumerate(L):
    L[i] = string + '.txt'
```

Comment: The first option is not semantically equivalent to the second. The second has the downside of aliasing `L[i]` with `string` which make it somewhat confusing. I think `+=` is better.